# Matplotlib crashes console - Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)

Tags: qt, matplotlib, ipython, anaconda

After a fresh install of `Anaconda 2.4.0/Python 3.5` on a 64-bit Windows 7, I can display a `matplotlib` window, but a brush of the mouse pointer over the window crashes `ipython / python`.

```
Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 07:26:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.


IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
In[1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random
a = numpy.random.rand(500,1)
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()

Backend Qt4Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

`python3.exe`, `ipython.exe`, and the `PyCharm Ipython` console all fail. Spyder Ipython console and Jupyter Qt console both can survive a matplotlib window.

All Interpreters point to the Anaconda 2.4.0 only install of python3 on the computer.

Ipython manages to get the following before a recursion limit is reached :

```
    C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\ipython.exe E:\owinter\PYTHON\echo\sandbox\test_matplotlib.py
    In [6]: Readline internal error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\seadline\console\console.py", line 768, in hook_wrapper_23
       res = ensure_str(readline_hook(prompt))
      File "C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\seadline\rlmain.py", line 571, in readline
        self._readline_from_keyboard()
      File "C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\seadline\rlmain.py", line 536, in _readline_from_keyboard
        if self._readline_from_keyboard_poll():
      File "C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\seadline\rlmain.py", line 552, in _readline_from_keyboard_poll
        event = c.getkeypress()
      File "C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\seadline\console\console.py", line 524, in getkeypress
        e = self.get()
      File "C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\seadline\console\console.py", line 514, in get
        call_function(inputHookFunc, ())
    OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000434DB8
```

Attached is the package list, unaltered and fresh from the Anaconda install
            `C:\Users\owinter>conda list`

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\owinter\AppData\Local\Continuu
#
alabaster                 0.7.6                    py35_0
anaconda                  2.4.0               np110py35_0
anaconda-client           1.1.0                    py35_0
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py35_1
astropy                   1.0.5               np110py35_1
babel                     2.1.1                    py35_0
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py35_0
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py35_1
blaze                     0.8.3                     <pip>
blaze-core                0.8.3                    py35_0
bokeh                     0.10.0                   py35_0
boto                      2.38.0                   py35_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_2  [vc14]
cffi                      1.2.1                    py35_0
clyent                    0.4.0                    py35_0
colorama                  0.3.3                    py35_0
comtypes                  1.1.2                    py35_0
conda                     3.18.3                   py35_0
conda-build               1.18.1                   py35_0
conda-env                 2.4.4                    py35_0
configobj                 5.0.6                    py35_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                    py35_1
cryptography              1.0.2                    py35_0
curl                      7.45.0                   vc14_0  [vc14]
cython                    0.23.4                   py35_0
cytoolz                   0.7.4                    py35_0
datashape                 0.4.7               np110py35_1
decorator                 4.0.4                    py35_0
docutils                  0.12                     py35_1
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py35_0
flask                     0.10.1                   py35_1
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_0  [vc14]
greenlet                  0.4.9                    py35_0
h5py                      2.5.0               np110py35_4
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                 vc14_3  [vc14]
idna                      2.0                      py35_0
ipykernel                 4.1.1                    py35_0
ipython                   4.0.0                    py35_1
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython-notebook          4.0.4                    py35_3
ipython-qtconsole         4.0.1                    py35_4
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0
ipywidgets                4.1.0                    py35_0
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0
jdcal                     1.0                      py35_0
jedi                      0.9.0                    py35_0
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_0
jpeg                      8d                       vc14_0  [vc14]
jsonschema                2.4.0                    py35_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_0
jupyter-client            4.1.1                     <pip>
jupyter-console           4.0.3                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.0.6                     <pip>
jupyter_client            4.1.1                    py35_0
jupyter_console           4.0.3                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.0.6                    py35_0
launcher                  1.0.0                         4
libpng                    1.6.17                   vc14_1  [vc14]
libsodium                 1.0.3                         0
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_0  [vc14]
lxml                      3.4.4                    py35_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_0
matplotlib                1.4.3               np110py35_3
menuinst                  1.2.1                    py35_0
mistune                   0.7.1                    py35_0
msvc_runtime              1.0.0                    vc14_0  [vc14]
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py35_0
nbconvert                 4.0.0                    py35_0
nbformat                  4.0.1                    py35_0
networkx                  1.10                     py35_0
nltk                      3.1                      py35_0
node-webkit               0.10.1                        0
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_0
notebook                  4.0.6                    py35_0
numexpr                   2.4.4               np110py35_0
numpy                     1.10.1                   py35_0
odo                       0.3.4                    py35_0
openpyxl                  2.2.6                    py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2d                   vc14_0  [vc14]
pandas                    0.17.0              np110py35_0
path.py                   8.1.2                    py35_0
patsy                     0.4.0               np110py35_0
pep8                      1.6.2                    py35_0
pickleshare               0.5                      py35_0
pillow                    3.0.0                    py35_1
pip                       7.1.2                    py35_0
ply                       3.8                      py35_0
psutil                    3.2.2                    py35_0
py                        1.4.30                   py35_0
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py35_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py35_0
pycparser                 2.14                     py35_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_3
pycurl                    7.19.5.1                 py35_1
pyflakes                  1.0.0                    py35_0
pygments                  2.0.2                    py35_0
pyopenssl                 0.15.1                   py35_1
pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py35_0
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py35_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py35_0
pytables                  3.2.2               np110py35_1
pytest                    2.8.1                    py35_0
python                    3.5.0                         2
python-dateutil           2.4.2                    py35_0
pytz                      2015.6                   py35_0
pywin32                   219                      py35_1
pyyaml                    3.11                     py35_2
pyzmq                     14.7.0                   py35_1
qt                        4.8.7                    vc14_4  [vc14]
qtconsole                 4.1.0                    py35_0
requests                  2.8.1                    py35_0
rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1
rope-py3k-0.9.4           1                         <pip>
scikit-image              0.11.3              np110py35_0
scikit-learn              0.16.1              np110py35_0
scipy                     0.16.0              np110py35_0
setuptools                18.4                     py35_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_0
sip                       4.16.9                   py35_1
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
snowballstemmer           1.2.0                    py35_0
sockjs-tornado            1.0.1                    py35_0
sphinx                    1.3.1                    py35_0
sphinx-rtd-theme          0.1.7                     <pip>
sphinx_rtd_theme          0.1.7                    py35_0
spyder                    2.3.7                    py35_3
spyder-app                2.3.7                    py35_0
sqlalchemy                1.0.9                    py35_0
statsmodels               0.6.1               np110py35_0
sympy                     0.7.6.1                  py35_0
tables                    3.2.2                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]
toolz                     0.7.4                    py35_0
tornado                   4.2.1                    py35_1
traitlets                 4.0.0                    py35_0
ujson                     1.33                     py35_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0
werkzeug                  0.10.4                   py35_0
wheel                     0.26.0                   py35_1
xlrd                      0.9.4                    py35_0
xlsxwriter                0.7.7                    py35_0
xlwings                   0.4.1                    py35_0
xlwt                      1.0.0                    py35_0
zeromq                    4.1.3                    vc14_1  [vc14]
zlib                      1.2.8                    vc14_2  [vc14]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By digging further I found out there was conflicting `Qt` libraries in this `Anaconda` install :

```
 Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40807) with this library (version 0x40804)
```

Next step was to look for the conflicting libraries in the command window:

```
 where QtGui*.dll
```

Then uninstall or remove from the path environment variable the softwares responsible.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the procedure? I am having the same issue, but I'm not able to fix it. 

What further digging did you do?

Comment: I've solved the similar issue I had, after updating my anaconda distro on win7, 64bit. @oliche 's point with the 'where'-command pointed me to my LaTeX distro, and after reinstalling that, everything works a charm.